# Error while trying to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 12.10

I recently purchased a new Toshiba Ultrabook that comes pre-installed with Windows 8. I'm trying to dual boot 12.10 with it and I have run into a problem with the installer. When I get to the page to pick the partitions I get this:

[image]

No drives are listed and the only thing in that device drop down is `/dev/sda`. If I click Install Now or +/-/change I get an "Ubuntu has stopped working" error message.

I'm trying to install off a 12.10 64-bit USB drive in UEFI mode, and I have tried it with secure boot both enabled and disabled with the same results.

The hard drive set up is as follows:

- 500 GB main drive

  - windows recovery (primary)
  - EFI boot section (primary)
  - Windows' partion (280 GB I believe) (primary)
  - unallocated space I created for Ubuntu partition (200ish GB)
  - another Windows recovery partition (primary)
- 12 GB solid state drive

  - all unallocated space

Could it be a problem with the number of primary partitions? I think I read somewhere about a max of 4.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**: Installing on HDD (`/dev/sda`).

What you have stated in your question is correct.

You can't have more than 4 primary partitions.

Since 4 primary partitions have already been alloted to Windows, you are unable create any Partition for Ubuntu. Ubuntu can be installed on Logical Partitions, so if you can free at least one of the Primary Partitions from Windows, you will have the ability to create multiple Logical Partitions on it, one of which can be alloted to Ubuntu.

From your description, I can see there are two Recovery partitions for Windows. I am not sure about how Partitions for Windows 8 work, but my best bet would be that one of those Recovery Partitions is redundant, one of which you should be able to remove.

But, before doing any changes to your Windows Partitions, I advise you to get to know the Partition Layout of Windows 8 and their respective uses, and then start.

**Case 2**: Installing on SSD (`/dev/sdb`)

If you don't want to mess around with your Windows 8 install, you can just select `/dev/sdb` in your install menu which should be your SSD.

So, you will now have Windows 8 on your HDD and Ubuntu on your SSD. But now, every time you boot, you will have to choose whether to boot from HDD or SSD.